# Database update with raw query not updating the table?

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I've been trying to update my table with the following query :

```
String updateQuery = "UPDATE TABLE SET COLUMN = 'HELLO' || COLUMN;"
dataBase.rawQuery(updateQuery,null);
```

The table is not updating the values inside the field **COLUMN** with the query.

However the table gets updated when i run the following command :

```
String updateQuery = "UPDATE TABLE SET COLUMN = 'HELLO' || COLUMN;"
Cursor updateCursor = dataBase.rawQuery(updateQuery,null);
updateCursor.moveToFirst();
updateCursor.close();
```

When i ran the command without using `updateCursor.moveToFirst()` the table didn't update itself but as soon as i added it above `updateCursor.close()` the table was updated. I tried searching about it a lot but didn't find anything either in the documentation or on blogs. Please help me understand the cause behind this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to use [`rawQuery`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#rawQuery%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29) when you do not return a result. You will have to do the second thing to properly close the Cursor.

Instead you can use [`execSQL`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#execSQL%28java.lang.String%29) or the more elegant [`update`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#update%28java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29) method.

If you want to understand why think of this:

If you have an SQL query that are reading from the database you would want to delay reading that data until you are certain that you will use it.

So when you call `rawQuery` you get a reference to a `Cursor` object. But nothing is read yet. This is what the `moveToFirst` does. It is the first thing that tells the cursor that you are serious about running this SQL query and that you want a result.

But since you are using `rawQuery` for an UPDATE nothing is passed on to the database before you try to fetch a result with `moveToFirst`.

Therefore you should use `execSQL` that actually runs the SQL query without waiting for you to request a result.

Comment: I agree with you mate, i could have avoided this query if i wanted to but just for my understanding, i wanna know that why is `updateCursor.moveToFirst();` required?

Comment: I do not know. You can try to find the source code for the class involved. This is just one of those things.

Comment: I've seen the source code, it says :                   **Parameters:**
sql the SQL query. The SQL string must not be ; terminated
selectionArgs You may include ?s in where clause in the query, which will be replaced by the values from selectionArgs. The values will be bound as Strings.

                                                         **Returns:**
A Cursor object, **which is positioned before the first entry**. Note that Cursors are not synchronized, see the documentation for more details.

Comment: I have edited my answer with a reason for why this is the case. See the code for [SQLiteCursor.java](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteCursor.java) onMove method. That is called from moveToFirst and is where the actual communication with the database is initiated.

Comment: What more do you expect from an answer @AndroidWarrior?

Comment: That's a great explanation and i might even accept it as an answer but i have coded for database UPDATE with `rawQuery` in earlier projetcs and there i didn't require `moveToFirst()` for having my code executed, then why is it required in some cases whereas in others it's not required?

Comment: Are you sure you didn't moveToFirst and used rawQuery. Can you recreate it? What version of Android SDK did you use when it happened?

Comment: Sorry for the late acceptance of your answer, but it's the best answer that i found.